# Request Tracker does not highlight a ticket when it receives a new reply

Tags: request-tracker

When a new ticket is created, I can see that in RT. But then if a new reply or correspondence comes to that ticket, it is not getting highlighted (but I can see the new correspondence in the ticket). Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to notify you if there are unread messages on a ticket:

http://bestpractical.com/rt/docs/latest/RT_Config.html#ShowUnreadMessageNotifications

This can be set as a global option or at the individual level by going to Logged in as > Settings > Options. Look for "Notify me of unread messages".

Comment: Thank you for the clue. But when we are at RT dashboard, we can't see any notification. I hope RT doesn't have that type of thing. I can see only the notification message inside the ticket.

Comment: To see it in a ticket list somewhere in "RT at a glance", click on Edit for the section you want (e.g., 10 highest priority tickets I own). In the Display Columns section, add UpdateStatus to the shown columns. That will work in conjunction with ShowUnreadMessageNotifications and show you new messages. You can click the link at the top of the page to clear the unread messages for a given ticket.

Comment: +1 for UpdateStatus column add to the dashboard... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Somethink like highlight ticket there are not possible (or I don't know, how to do it), but my advice is to change sorting of ticket not according to priority (which is default choice), but to last activity. You will see ticket, which have very last activity as the first. Or, if you need sorting according to priority, you can add last activity as the second rule of sorting criterium.

BTW: I used tickets, which I replied to it, mark as resolved. In this case they go out from default views on the Dashboard, but after user reply to it, it will be reopened and goes to the Dashboard again.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for that idea. But by the word highlighting, I mean like when you get a new ticket, that ticket will be in "bold". The other ticketing systems has it. So I thought, I have made something wrong.